# How to animate the map fragment in Google Maps API for Android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments, material-design, android-animation

I am developing an app that uses Google Maps API for Android. I want to create the animation effect similar to Google Maps app for Android which keeps the map fragment above the bottom sheet no matter what its state is. Following is the effect:

[image]

I tried the `Map.setPadding()` given [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map#map_padding) to shift the map components above the bottom sheet (by calculating the height of the bottom sheet at run-time and passing it as the parameter to the mentioned method) and then refreshing the layout using `ViewGroup.invalidate()` and then `ViewGroup.requestLayout()` but I could not generate effect as smooth as Google Maps app. Another solution that I think of was to use Activity Transition but don't know how to achieve it in Fragments. Please help. Thanks in advance!:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself. It's very simple. If you are using `BottomSheetBehavior` for Android to implement the bottom sheet then in its `onStateChanged()` method you can perform the camera animation for Google Maps. It is a camera animation that is performed after the state of the bottom sheet changes with the help of `CameraUpdateFactory.scrollBy(float, float)` that allows you to shift the camera position on x and y axes. Further details can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/CameraUpdateFactory.html#scrollBy(float,%20float)).

I am just changing the vertical y-axis as I want the map to move (or adjust) vertically and passing it to `mMap.animateCamera()` method. The `bs_height` is the height of the bottom sheet that I calculated at the run-time.

Following snippet shows how:

```
@Override
    public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
        switch (newState) {
            case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED :
                collapsedStateAnimation();
                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.scrollBy(0.0f, bs_height - 200));
                break;
            case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_DRAGGING :
               ...
                break;
            case BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED :
                    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.scrollBy(0.0f, bs_height + 200));
                break;
        }
    }
```